# Разбить множество на два случайных подмножества

Tags: python

Есть множество строк, полученное из списка удалением дубликатов:

```
keys = []
# заполнение списка keys
st = set(keys)
```

Нужно получить два множества `st1` и `st2` такие, что их объединение есть исходное множество `st`, и они не пересекаются, причём разбить случайным образом так, чтобы любое разбиение (а их всего `2^{st.size}`) было равновероятно.

Как это можно сделать в python'е ?

Comment: Уточните, как к проблеме разбиения множества относится его происхождение? *(вероятно никак)*

Comment: Думаю да, никак :) Но мало ли, вдруг там есть способ это как-то сделать до удаления дубликатов, поэтому я на всякий случай этот кусок кода также оставил...

Answer (score 1):

Сгенерировать случайное число от 0 до `2^{st.size}-1` и сопоставить единицы в его бинарном представлении с номерами элементов, составляющих первое подмножество.

Однако `set` не поддерживает индексацию, и для выполнения извлечения определённых элементов, видимо, придётся вернуться обратно к списку.

Comment: В множестве около 300000 элементов ( В плюсах я бы не взялся генерировать такой диапазон случайных чисел, в питоне, конечно, не уверен, но боюсь у него тоже будут проблемы...

Comment: Это просто набор нулей и единиц, каждый с вероятностью 0.5, аналогично бросанию монеты - т.е. генерируем список нулей и единиц, каждый независимо. Да и сам этот список нулей не нужен - просто с вероятностью 0.5 берем каждый элемент множества (списка) в результат. Так что никаких проблем нет.

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я не додумался сам. А если дополнительно мы к этому захотим, чтобы в разбиении было одно множество с конкретным числом элементов, то есть, скажем, ровно 100 единиц, сложно модифицировать алгоритм для такого случая?

Comment: хотя, пожалуй, я знаю - генерим рандомное число от 1 до `size()`, этот номер "берём", потом генерим опять рандомное в таком же диапазоне, если сгенерили уже взятое - повторяем генерацию, и так, пока не наберём нужное количество...

Comment: Можно ещё использовать алгоритм [reservoir sampling](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling)